# Why React example does not use Async call to fetch json of requested page

Tags: aem

I am following this tutorials: https://github.com/adobe/aem-sample-we-retail-journal

Here, all the child pages JSON is stored into **INITIAL_STATE** id.

https://github.com/adobe/aem-sample-we-retail-journal/blob/master/react-app/src/index.js#L34

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
let jsonScript = document.getElementById("__INITIAL_STATE__");
let initialState = null;
if (jsonScript) {
    initialState = JSON.parse(jsonScript.innerText);
    // Remove the script element from the DOM
    jsonScript.remove();
}
```

I want to know why it is done in this way, can someone please explain?

Instead what if I navigate on different links and then on click of each links if I call model json of that page via Async fetch and then accordingly set **INITIAL_STATE** id. What problem in this approach?

Comment: I would suggest you post the code that you are talking about. You should not expect people to jump to a git repository, scan code and try to interprete your text - only to help you answer your question.

Comment: @OliverGebert thanks for your suggestion, updated the post, I think people who have followed this tutorial would understand what I am talking about, because just adding only a small piece of code will not make any difference.

Comment: It _seems_ to me the code you are referring to is the local server code for development. It seems the initial state you are referring to is used within the express dev server and NOT while the react app runs on AEM. If you look at the current AEM archtype https://github.com/adobe/aem-project-archetype you'll see it actually uses a proxy. The git repo you are working with might be a bit old, but still functional nonetheless.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam, I am not sure you have ran this example or not, maybe you can first try in your local. This is Server Side Rendering of react so, there is no need of proxy as AEM is posting whole content tree to Node server and Node server giving back the HTML response